# SQL UNION on group by and an aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union

I wrote a query which presents the top 5 average amounts per id and then the averages of all ids except the top 5.
When i wrote it like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 cast(lefty1.id as varchar) AS id, AVG(lefty1.amount) avg_amount
FROM left_table lefty1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC
UNION
SELECT 'others' AS id, AVG(lefty2.amount) AS avg_amount
FROM left_table lefty2
WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT TOP 5 lefty1.id AS id
FROM left_table lefty1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC)
```

It gave me an error.
But when I wrote it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 cast(lefty1.id as varchar) AS id, AVG(lefty1.amount) avg_amount
FROM left_table lefty1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC) AS a
UNION
SELECT 'others' AS id, AVG(lefty2.amount) AS avg_amount
FROM left_table lefty2
WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT TOP 5 lefty1.id AS id
FROM left_table lefty1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC)
```

It worked. why?

Comment: Rule of thumbs one, when you say `It gave me an error.` in any question on stack overflow, then also add the error message in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

In a UNION query the ORDER BY clause comes last and affects the whole result. If you have ORDER BY in the partial queries (in order to apply a top clause) you need parentheses.

You would have placed the parentheses best as follows:

```
(
  SELECT TOP 5 
    cast(lefty1.id as varchar) AS id, 
    AVG(lefty1.amount) avg_amount
  FROM left_table lefty1
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 
    'others' AS id, 
    AVG(lefty2.amount) AS avg_amount
  FROM left_table lefty2
  WHERE id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT TOP 5 lefty1.id AS id
    FROM left_table lefty1
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY AVG(amount) DESC
  )
);
```

I also replaced `UNION` with the simpler `UNION ALL` as there are obviously no duplicates to remove.

BTW: Your result rows are not necessarily ordered. If you want them ordered you would have to specify an according order by clause at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two `ORDER BY` clauses when you use a `UNION/UNION ALL`.

By wrapping your first `SELECT` in `(SELECT...) AS A` you bypassed this syntax check as the first `ORDER BY` now happens within the parenthesis, and BEFORE the `UNION` occurs.